# Getting this crash in comparison method or anywher else cant get it

Tags: android, comparison, android-viewgroup

I am getting this Crash. i cant figure from where its coming in android.I search at many place they say, JAVA changed compparison method sorting logic, i did not used any sorting though i am getting this error

```
Fatal Exception: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
           at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(ComparableTimSort.java:831)
           at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:449)
           at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:372)
           at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:178)
           at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:142)
           at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1957)
           at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1864)
           at android.view.ViewGroup$ChildListForAccessibility.init(ViewGroup.java:6886)
           at android.view.ViewGroup$ChildListForAccessibility.obtain(ViewGroup.java:6851)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.addChildrenForAccessibility(ViewGroup.java:1727)
           at android.view.ViewGroup.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(ViewGroup.java:2634)
           at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:5227)
           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(FrameLayout.java:651)
           at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:5188)
           at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:5175)
           at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:811)
           at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:834)
           at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:834)
           at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:720)
           at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:147)
           at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$300(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:49)
           at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:971)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)'
```

Comment: what are the types of `CardValue` and `CardColor`?

Comment: cardValue and cardColor are of  int type

Answer (score 1):

As the exception says , the the compare function is invalid.

Example for invalid compare function can be:

1. compare(A,B) shows A < B
2. compare(B,C) shows B < C
3. compare(A,C) shows A > C

This is invalid order since the (1+2) implies A < C

Comment: Why did you enclose the code in `try catch` block ? which exception is thrown ? show all the code of the compare function ...

Comment: I just add try catch block to avoid crash. and this is whole block of code of my compareTo method.

Comment: It is probably the problem. you can **not guess** that the objects are equal when exception is thrown. The code in the `try` should not throw exception.

Comment: I removed that comparison method still getting this crash